# Creation of Threads in a for loop

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop

I currently have the following code:

```
String [] names = {"Fred","Perry","Dave","Tom"};
for (String s: names) {           
Threads greetings = new Threads(s); 
}
```

And this works fine - however what i am doing is assigning Fred","Perry","Dave","Tom" all to greetings.

What i wish to do is the following

```
greetings0 = Tom
greetings1 = Perry
greetings2 = Dave
greetings3 = Tom
```

This will mean i can later on run greetings.start(); greetings1.start() etc at the same time in its own thread.

Comment: Well it's `Thread` not `Threads`.  Could we see some code that compiles?

Comment: I have improved the question as it wasnt to clear

Comment: If you *really* must have those variable names, you can't do that in a loop. You *should* use an array or list (as suggested in Josh's answer) as this lets you use a loop and keeps the code simpler.

Comment: @Chris but how do i incorporate the variable names greetings* into this?

Comment: @Chris this is where i am stuck

Comment: `Thread greetings0 = new Thread("Tom"); Thread greetings1 = new Thread("Perry");`, etc. You can't do this in a loop if you want to have your variable names like this. However, there's no value in that, so I'll again strongly recommend using a list or array as in Josh's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a list of Thread objects, each one with the assigned name. You are trying to create dynamic variable names which isn't possible. Here is how to loop through the names and add each named Thread to a List.

I hope this is what you were looking for. It's a little unclear in your problem description about what you want with greetings, greetings1,greetings2,greetings3.

```
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    String [] names = {"Fred","Perry","Dave","Tom"};
    for (String s : names){           
        threads.add(new Thread(s));
    }
```

EDIT: Since you said you will only ever have 4 greetings then you can do this:

```
Thread greeting = new Thread("Fred");
Thread greeting1 = new Thread("Perry");
Thread greeting2 = new Thread("Dave");
Thread greeting3 = new Thread("Tom");
```

You can also do this if you want to keep them in a List for some reason:

```
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
String[] names = { "Fred", "Perry", "Dave", "Tom" };
for(String s : names)
{
    threads.add(new Thread(s));
}
Thread greeting = threads.get(0);
Thread greeting1 = threads.get(1);
Thread greeting2 = threads.get(2);
Thread greeting3 = threads.get(3);
```

Comment: Hello Josh not quite what i want, but that is my fault for not explaining properly. I am going to improve my question

Comment: Are you always going to have exactly 4 greetings?

Comment: @ Josh Chappelle yes i will always have 4 greetings

Comment: I edited my answer with how to do what I think you are wanting. I hope that helps.

Comment: @ Josh of course - call the index of the Arraylist, thats brilliant - many thanks